# Print strings if there is not only single asterisk sign regexp

Tags: regex, bash

I have the next strings in file:

```
check.test1[*]
othercheck.sometest[*] and so on
```

I want if square brackets contain anything else except asterisk - print such string, but if there is just an asterisk do not output that string.

For example:

```
   check.test1[*,131] - print such string as long as it contains digits and comma
   check.test2[a,bc,,*,777] - print such string as long as it contains letters,commans and digits. 
   check.test2[* ] - print such string as long as it contains 1 space.
   check.test[*] - do not print such string as long as there is only asterisk.
```

I want to do it in Bash.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece uses reverse grep search.

data.file contains:

```
    check.test1[*,131]
    check.test2[a,bc,,*,777]
    check.test2[* ]
    check.test[*]
```

Just run:

```
    grep -v '\[\*\]' /path/to/data.file
```

With output:

```
    check.test1[*,131]
    check.test2[a,bc,,*,777]
    check.test2[* ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I need!